# Flask cannot raise HTTP exception after try catching Runtime error

Tags: python, flask, exception

When I try to raise a HTTP exception status code 400 it only prints the json error message on the browser but does not state `HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST` in the console like it is supposed to. The exception raising works for all other parts of my program but it doesn't work when I do it in a try-catch for a runtime error.

My exception handler is exactly this:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/apierrors/

my try-catch:

```
try:
    // run some program
catch RuntimeError as e:
    raise InvalidUsage(e.message, status_code=400)
```

Comment: You code example is not valid Python, as `//` is not a comment marker in Python. It is also not complete, as the definition of the `InvalidUser` class is missing, as is the code in the `try` block. Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit] your question to make it better.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `abort` function of flask, something like:

```
from flask import abort

@app.route("/some_route")
def some_route():
    try:
        # do something
    except SomeException:
         abort(400, "Some message")
```

Comment: It should actually be `abort(400, "Some message")`